# SwipeableContainer doesn't work correctly on Android

Tags: codenameone

I've an issue with SwipeableContainer that occurs only on Android.

I instanciate like this :

```
this.buttonRemoveExam = new Button();
this.buttonRemoveExam.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.buttonRemoveExam.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
this.buttonRemoveExam.setIcon(REMOVE);
this.buttonRemoveExam.setPressedIcon(REMOVE_PRESSED);
this.containerTop = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
this.containerTop.setUIID("ContainerScoreGraphique");       
this.containerTop.addComponent(labelNameScore);
this.containerTop.addComponent(labelDateExam);
this.containerTop.addComponent(containerButtons);
this.swipeableContainer = new SwipeableContainer(buttonRemoveExam, containerTop);
```

The problem is when an swipe to the right, buttonRemoveExam doesn't appear correctly (only 1 or 2 px).

I've debug it in Android Studio. I put breakpoint in animate method of SwipeableContainer. It invoke `topWrapper.setX(100)` :

```
@Override
public boolean animate() {
    if (openCloseMotion != null) {
        int val = openCloseMotion.getValue();
        if (openedToRight) {
            topWrapper.setX(val);
        } else {
            topWrapper.setX(-val);
        }

        repaint();
        boolean finished = openCloseMotion.isFinished();
        if (finished) {
            //getComponentForm().deregisterAnimated(this);
            openCloseMotion = null;
            if(!open){
                bottomRightWrapper.setVisible(false);
                bottomLeftWrapper.setVisible(false);
                openedToLeft = false;
                openedToRight = false;
            }else{
                dispatcher.fireActionEvent(new ActionEvent(this,ActionEvent.Type.Swipe));                
            }
        }
        return !finished;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have no problem in simulator and iOS version.

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried the swipe container on my android with the kitchen sink demo and it worked. Is it possible the icon is broken in Android? If you set text to the button does it work?

Comment: I've tried with text only but doesn't work at all. With image, it appears a bit (1 or 2 px). FYI, I run it on samsung tab (galaxy tab A 2016) with Android 6.0.1

Comment: Does it happen in the simulator if you use an Android skin?

Comment: Good idea, but no problem with Android skin. I've also tried to put the button on the right side but same behavior

Comment: Does swiping work with the kitchen sink demo (under contacts) in that device?

Comment: Yes it works well ...

Comment: So how is your application different?

Comment: Seems that there is a problem with my layout. I've tried to replace "topWrapper.setX(val);" by "topWrapper.getAllStyles().setMargin(Component.LEFT,val);" in animate method of SwipeableContainer class and it works.
Can't find why setX doesn't work correctly in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the X coordinate of a component as the actual coordinates are set by the layout manager. The only case where setting a coordinate is valid is if you intend to do an `animateLayout` type of operation in which case this will only work if there is no `revalidate` along the way.

Comment: What I mentionned in my previous comment about problem with "setX" is actually located on the codenameone side (animate method of SwipeableContainer.java)

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but then you mentioned you edited it. Is it possible revalidate/repaint or some other method is triggered here in your code?

Comment: I've edited it in the source code of codenameone in Android studio (while debugging). I've seen no revalidate or repaint in my code.
I think a good idea could be to refactor your SwipeableContainer class to change margin instead of X position which doesn't always work

Comment: I tend to agree but I didn't write the component so I'm not sure about the implications. Please file an issue and reference this question, I'll ask.